# how to install mono latest Alpha version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mono, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to do the guide on the mono website, but I don't really understand it as I am not a linux guy and surely not an expert in servers.

I don't find anything on Google.

No matter what I do, when I use the "mono --version" command to see if the install was successful, I get Mono 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for alpha versions, you will want to setup your package manager to pull the Mono **Continuous Integration packages** as these are built for every commit to the repo at https://github.com/mono/mono.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://jenkins.mono-project.com/repo/debian sid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-jenkins.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Ref: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Read the [Usage](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/#usage) section on how to select a build/package.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to do it in Terminal and I needed the command for installing it after I did all the things they say on their page, which was "sudo apt-get install mono-complete" and "sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-mono"